# App Windows as Widgets

Tags: app-widgets, xposed-framework, multi-window, overlay

I want to pin an app window to the home screen, like a widget, except that it is a live app.

I need this because there are so many applications which do not have any widgets. Instead of opening an app(which I forget most of the time) I would like to have them pinned as a widget which I can easily view while scrolling through the home screens.

There any many Xposed modules, which allow any app to be viewed as a floating window, but don't know how to make widgets out of them.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not an easy task. But let me contribute with some milestones.
First of all the Home app will need to handle it. It's not just a view inside the app, like widgets do. Because a RemoteView is extremely limited, it makes no sense to try to convert "normal" activities to a widget.
But the good news is that Android implemented about 2 years ago the "multi window".
Maybe there is someone that made a hack, but I'm sure it'll need a custom ROM, because there is no API to handle multi window from an app. An app can just handle its own behavior in multi window.

I'll follow this question. :P

Comment: There are many Xposed modules for multiple floating windows, like [XFHW](https://github.com/shooash/XHFW3), which works really well. If a widget is pretty limited, will it be feasible to display the contents of an app window directly over the widget, thus giving the illusion of a widget. Or to just display the contents of the app window as a RemoteView, which is updated continuously.

Comment: I think the first option is more feasible, display an app directly over the widget area. The second is not possible because many views/widgets are not supported by RemoteViews (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews ).